# How to select a portion of rows from a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, rows

I need to select X rows from a table starting at position Y; a specific column is used for ordering the table.

This query almost works:

```
DECLARE @Index int
DECLARE @Count int

SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT TOP (@Count) * FROM
    (
        SELECT TOP (@Index + @Count) * FROM Table
        ORDER BY Table.OrderColumn ASC
    ) AS T1
    ORDER BY T1.OrderColumn DESC
) AS T2
ORDER BY T2.OrderColumn ASC
```

However, if there aren't enough rows in the table (say, the table has 120 rows and I want 50 rows starting from position 100), this query just ignores the starting position and returns the last X rows.

Also, using three levels of SELECTs and ordering strikes me as quite bad performance-wise.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a variation that may work

```
DECLARE @Index int = 5403
DECLARE @Count int = 1000

SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT TOP (@Index + @Count) *,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by OrderColumn) as Sequence
    FROM MyTable
    ORDER BY MyTable.OrderColumn ASC
) as T
WHERE Sequence BETWEEN @Index and @Index + @Count - 1
ORDER BY OrderColumn
```

The derived table (nested query) shouldn't hurt performance.  SQL Server will optimize for it.  Although it will depend on the what the real query looks like.

Comment: The actual query simply retrieves the rows, at most it filters on a single column value.

Comment: Works great. Just a couple of comments: the last `ORDER BY` is reduntant (the rows are already ordered), and the `BETWEEN` clause should be `BETWEEN @Index + 1 AND @Index + @Count`, otherwise you have to use a base-1 index.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Actually, the last `ORDER BY` is not redundant.  The optimizer determined that sorting the data was best to get the results.  If it finds a different way to get the results, the sequence is not guaranteed unless you include the last `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: I find this to be quite puzzling... in order to compute ROW_NUMBER, the database engine *HAS* to order the rows as requested. I can't possibly conceive a scenario where it would be able to compute ROW_NUMBER without ordering them.

Comment: Anyway, if the rows are already ordered, a redundant `ORDER BY` clause isn't probably going to do any harm...

Answer (score 0):

If SQL 2012 is used OFFSET clause may be handy, a sample based on AdventureWorks is provided below :-

```
DECLARE @Index int = 100 DECLARE @Count int = 50

SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate, CustomerID, SalesPersonID  
FROM  Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
ORDER BY OrderDate, SalesOrderID 
OFFSET @Index ROWS FETCH NEXT @Count ROWS ONLY;
```

if it is SQL2008, windows functions with CTE would be helpful, a sample based on AdventureWorks:-

```
DECLARE @Index int = 100
DECLARE @Count int = 50

;WITH C AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY OrderDate,SalesOrderID ) AS rownum,
SalesOrderID, OrderDate, CustomerID, SalesPersonID
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
)
SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate, CustomerID, SalesPersonID
FROM C
WHERE rownum BETWEEN @Index + 1  AND @Index + @Count 
ORDER BY rownum;
```